# How to combine reference and mvreference entry types by splitting the bibliography?

Tags: biblatex

MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
            lmodern,
            babel,
            csquotes,
            filecontents
           }
\usepackage[
            backend = biber,
            sortlocale = auto,
            sorting = nyt,
            style = authoryear-comp
           ]{biblatex}

\newcommand*\english[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

  @REFERENCE{Dreyhaupt,
             EDITOR    = {Dreyhaupt, Franz-Josef},
             LOCATION  = {Berlin and Heidelberg},
             PUBLISHER = {Springer},
             URL       = {https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-95750-5},
             DATE      = {1994},
             ISBN      = {978-3-642-957\,51-2},
             TITLE     = {VDI-Lexikon Umwelttechnik},
            }

  @MVREFERENCE{Janes,
               AUTHOR    = {Jackson FRAeS, Paul},
               EDITOR    = {\english{Jane's}\textsuperscript{\textregistered}},
               LOCATION  = {\english{Coulsdon, Surrey} (GB)},
               PUBLISHER = {IHS Markit},
               DATE      = {2017},
               EDITION   = {2017--2018},
               ISBN      = {978\,0\,71\,06\,32\,50\,0},
               SUBTITLE  = {\english{Development \& Production}},
               TITLE     = {\english{All the World's Aircraft}},
              }

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

  \chapter{Test chapter}

    Test \autocite{Dreyhaupt}. Test \autocite{Janes}.

  \addchap{Bibliografie}

    \printbibliography[
                       type = reference,
                       title = Nachlagewerke
                      ]
\end{document}
```

How can I have both entry types (`@reference` and `@mvreference`) listed under one bibliography heading (*Nachlagewerke*)?

Comment: Since you were into ISO 690 the last time, note that §9.1.2 *Multiple places* says: "If two or more place names appear equally prominently [...], only the first place name should be given." which probably means you only want `location = {Berlin},`

Comment: Hello @moewe! Thank you for your comment! You are right! Thank you for the hint and correction of my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter multiple types, you need a bibfilter.

```
\defbibfilter{references}{%
  type=reference or type=mvreference
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend = biber, style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\defbibfilter{references}{%
  type=reference or type=mvreference
}

\newcommand*\english[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@reference{Dreyhaupt,
  editor    = {Dreyhaupt, Franz-Josef},
  location  = {Berlin and Heidelberg},
  publisher = {Springer},
  url       = {https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-95750-5},
  date      = {1994},
  isbn      = {978-3-642-95751-2},
  title     = {VDI-Lexikon Umwelttechnik},
}
@mvreference{Janes,
  editor    = {Jackson, Paul},
  location  = {Coulsdon, Surrey},
  publisher = {IHS Markit},
  date      = {2017},
  edition   = {2017--2018},
  isbn      = {9780710632500},
  subtitle  = {Development \& Production},
  title     = {Jane's All the World's Aircraft},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Test \autocite{Dreyhaupt}. Test \autocite{Janes}.

  \printbibheading
  \printbibliography[filter = references, heading=subbibliography, title = Nachlagewerke]
\end{document}
```

[image: Both works are listed under *Nachslagewerke*]